# What is the textarea character limit if a maxlength is not specified?

Tags: html, textarea, maxlength

So I've read that maxlength's default value is 524288 for a textarea.

So, if I don't specify a maxlength, will the textarea box only accept 524288 characters? Or will it accept an infinite amount of characters?

I apologize if this has been asked before or answered before; I'm just confused by what "default value" means in this context.

Answer (score 2):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) the default of maxLength is not limited at all (unlimited).

> If this value isn't specified, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters.

You can limit this by using attribute maxlength (but from your question i guess you already know how :) )
Example:

```
 <textarea maxlength="100"> Enter text here... </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the default value : 524288, you can put that many characters if you aren't using max.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Also, one follow-up question - if I want to store more than 524288 characters, can I set maxlength to a higher number (like say, 1 million)? Or would that be considered invalid?

Comment: You can check out more on this link , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength .